# GPRS module AT command HTTP Post request

Tags: post, at-command, gprs

i am using the GL865-DUAL GPRS module from Telit. 
I'm trying to set up a HTTP POST request to a website with my location variables. 
I am able to set up a working GPRS connection wit h the provider (got ip adres) but at the post at-command it goes wrong,
this is my command set:

```
"AT"                    //response: OK //build in delay of 5 seconds

Delay after each AT command set to 400miliseconds

"AT+CGMR                //response: 16.00.152 OK
"AT#QSS?"               //response: #QSS:0,1 OK
"AT#QSS=?"              // response #QSS: (0-2) OK
"AT+CMEE=1"             //response: OK
"AT+CMEE?"              // response: +CMEE: 1
"AT+CPIN?"              // response: +CPIN: READY OK
"AT+COPS?"              // response: +COPS: 0,0,"PROXIMUS" OK
"AT+CSQ"                // response: +CSQ: 20
"AT+cgatt=1"            // response: OK
"AT+CGDCONT=1,          \"IP\",\"internet.proximus.be\""     // response: OK // double quotes in c are expressed as \"
"AT+CGDCONT?"           // response: +CGDCONT: 1,"IP","internet.proximus.be","",0,0 OK
"AT#SGACT?"             // response: #SGACT: 1,0 OK
"AT#SCFG=?"             //#SCFG: (1-6,(0-5),(0-1500),(0-65535),(10-1200),(0-255) OK
"AT#SCFG=1,1,300,90,600,50"   // response: OK 
"AT#SGACT?"             //response: #SGACT: 1,0 
"AT#SGACT = 1,1"        //response: #SGACT: 178,144.233.116 OK
"AT#HTTPCFG=1,\"https://www.google.be/\",80,0,,,0,120,1"      // response: OK
"AT#HTTPSND=1,0,\"search?q=yo\",4,\"1:charset=ISO-8859-1\"test"   // response: CME Error 4
```

What am i doing wrong and is it possible to give a working example ?
Note: no Pin is required for the SIM card and no APN user and password is needed for my case.

Folowing documents could be helpful:

```
http://www.gaw.ru/pdf/DIA_Telecom/80000ST10028_Easy%20GPRS%20User%20Guide_r1.pdf
http://www4.telit.com/module/infopool/download.php?id=542
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the https:// and the trailing /. #HTTPCFG asks for a hostname or IP address, not a url.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your commands:

1. Your profile ID for HTTPCFG and HTTPSND don't match.
2. I think you need double quotes in your password and username fields
   for HTTPCFG.

Answer (score 0):

After AT#HTTPSND, the modem replies with >>> indicating that you need to supply Your data. The "test" at the end of that line shouldn't be there, it should be after a delay. you can try specifying just 1 for plain text and not the whole charset. Posting to google?